# Halmos's set theory If $E$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers, exists some $k$ in $E$ such that $k \leqq m$ for all $m\in E$. Prove by intersection

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

### Update

I saw a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112125/proof-of-well-ordering-principle-for-the-set-of-positive-integers-with-directly) which provided a proof by using axiom of induction and I wrote an answer by adapting to one of the answers of that question. But I hope someone can give another proof by using the intersection approach which I have explained at the end of my question.

---

In [Halmos set theory, page 52](https://books.google.de/books?id=lgdJDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) there is an exercise. The last part of which reads:

> Prove that if $E$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers, then there exists an element $k$ in $E$ such that $k \leqq m$ for all $m$ in $E$.

How can we prove this based on what we know so far in the book?

So far in the book we know the following which might be relevant for a proof:

1. For every natural number $n$ we have $n^+ = n \cup\{n\}$
2. No natural number is subset of any of its elements.
3. Every element of a natural number is a subset of it.
4. If $m$ and $n$ are distinct natural numbers then $m\in n$⟺$m \subset n$.
5. For every two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ we have exactly one of these: $m\in n$ or $n \in m$ or $m=n$.
6. if $m \in n$ or equivalently $m$ is a proper subset of $n$, we shall write $m \lt n$.
7. if $m$ is known to be either less than or equal to $n$ we write $m \leqq n$

Also we have five Peano axioms for the set of natural numbers $\omega$

1. $0 \in \omega$
2. if $n \in \omega$, then $n^+ \in \omega$
3. if $S \subset \omega$, if $0 \in S$, and if $n^+ \in S$ whenever $n \in S$, then $S = \omega$
4. $n^+ \neq 0$ for all $n$ in $\omega$
5. if $n$ and $m$  are in $\omega$ , and if $n^+ = m^+$, then $n=m$

ZF Axioms so far:

1. Extension
2. Specification
3. Pairing
4. Union
5. Powerset
6. Infinity

Possible proof sketch based on intersection of natural numbers:

1. define $s = \cap E$ (because $E$ is a non-empty collection of sets, its intersection is defined)
2. show that $s \in \omega$ (**I'm stuck at this part**)
3. show that $s \in E$
4. show that $s \leqq m$ for all m in $E$

Comment: I don’t speak German so I can’t read the book. This fact is known as the “well-ordering principle”; you can find proofs of the well-ordering principle from strong induction fairly easily.

Comment: @mark-saving the book is in English. I want a proof based on what we know in the book so far not just a proof.

Comment: I think if I can prove that every non-empty set of natural numbers is itself a subset of one natural number, I can prove the rest by induction.

Comment: I can't see all the pages of the book.  I guess that "what we know so far in the book" includes the Peano axioms and the recursion theorem; what else?

Comment: @nate-eldredge We know that for every two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ we have exactly one of these: $m\in n$ or $n \in m$ or $m = n$. Also we know that if $m$ and $n$ are distinct natural numbers then $m\in n \iff m \subset n$. Also no natural number is subset of any of its elements and every element of a natural number is a subset of it.

Comment: It's not true that every non-empty set of natural numbers is a subset of a single natural number.  It's true for finite sets, but false for infinite sets.  It's better form to edit your question to provide the information in the comment above.  The link you provide omits many pages of the book, at least for some of us.

Comment: @robert-shore If we can show the intersection of a non-empty set of integers is in the set, then the rest is very easy, I think.

Comment: I think you want to prove that the intersection of any non-empty set of natural numbers is itself a natural number.  It looks like you have enough to prove that.  You'll then want to prove that the intersection is in fact in the set.  At that point you're pretty much done.

Comment: @robert-shore Yes, I think this is a correct method for proving but maybe there are other workarounds, too.

Answer (score 1):

We use the axiom of induction but first we need a lemma.

### lemma:

$s \lt t^+ \implies s \leqq t$

proof: $s \lt t^+ \implies 
s\in t^+ \implies 
s\in t\cup\{t\} \implies 
s\in t \lor s=t \implies 
s\lt t \lor s=t\implies
s \leqq t$

### main proof by induction

Suppose $E$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers. Define $S$ as a subset of $\omega$ such that if any element of $S$ is a memeber of $E$ then there exists some $k\in E$ such that for all $m\in E$ we have $ k \leqq m$.

First we prove $0\in S$. Then we prove if $n\in S$ then $n^+ \in S$. And by using axiom of induction we get $S=\omega$ which means if any natural number is a member of $E$ then there exists some $k\in E$ such that for all $m\in E$ we have $k \leqq m$

$S = \{n\in\omega:$ if $n\in E$ then there exists an element $k \in E$ such that $k\leqq m$ for all $m \in E\}$.

### (base case of induction)

$0 \in S$ because if $0 \in E$ then $k=0$ and $k\leqq m$ for all $m\in E$

### (hypothesis of induction)

Suppose $n \in S$ means that if $n\in E$ then there exists some $k \in E$ such that $k \leqq m$ for all $m \in E$

### (step of induction)

supposing that $n \in S$, we need to prove that $n^+ \in S$ which means if $n^+\in E$ then there  exists some $k \in E$ such that $k \leqq m$ for all $m \in E$

Suppose $n^+ \in E$

If for all $m \in E$  we have $n^+ \leqq m$ then such $k$ exists and $k=n^+$

On the other hand $n^+$ does not satisfy and there exists some $j\in E$ such that $j  < n^+$ then $j \leqq n$.

We consider the set $E'=E \cup  \{n\}$. Now $E'$ is a non-empty subset of $\omega$ and $n \in E'$ so $E'$ satisfies induction hypothesis. So there exists $k' \in E'$ such that for all $m\in E'$ we have $k' \leqq m$. Now either $k' \in E$ or $k' = n$.

If $k'\in E$ then there is no problem. If $k' = n$ then we have $j \leqq n = k'$  and $k' \leqq j$ which gives $j\leqq k' \leqq j$ which gives $j = k' = n \in E$ and proof is done.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant property here is: If $n\neq m$ then either $n<m$ or $n>m$, and all elements of $n$ are subsets of $n$. So this means: $n$ contains exactly all natural numbers that are smaller than $n$.

Now consider a non-empty set of natural numbers $E$. Then we will show that the minimum of $E$ is the intersection $m$ of $E$. This then contains exactly all $n$ that are smaller than anything in $E$. Also as $m$ cannot be element of itself we’d get that $m$ must be in $E$ if we knew that $m$ is in fact a natural number. (Because then if it was not in $E$ it would either be smaller than anything in $E$, thus an element of itself, or it would be larger than one Element of $E$ which would thus be smaller than itself).

Since we do not know this, we walk a different path: Suppose $m\neq 0$ (if $m=0$ it is a natural number), then $m$ contains $0$. Suppose for one $n\in m$ we’d get $n^+\not\in m$. Then there must be a $k\in E$ so that $n^+\not < k$. But as $n<k$ this means that $k\not < n^+$. Thus $k=n^+$. But then $k$ contains all Elements smaller than $k$ and also only elements in $m$. Thus $m=k$.

Now if no such $n$ exists then by Peano we get $m=\mathbb N$, which would contradict to it’s definition and $E\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Please explain more clearly in your proof that why intersection of elements of $E$ is a natural number. This part is the key of the proof.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi Sure. Up to which part is it clear? The basic idea is that unless $m=\mathbb N$ or $m=0$ there has to be one $n\in m$ so that $n^+\in E$. Is this the part that is not clear? Or the part that if this does in fact hold we have $m=n^+$?

Comment: you want to prove that $m$ is a natural number. a natural number is either zero or non-zero. if m is zero, it is done. but if it is non-zero, why do you say it contains zero?

Comment: you say because $m$ can not be an element of itself and if $m$ is a natural number, then $m$ must be in $E$. why?

Comment: @OmidSadeghi 1) $m$ contains all natural numbers that are smaller than any number in $E$. If $m$ is not $0$ it contains at least one number, and as $0$ is smaller than any other number thus also $0$.

2) If $m$ is a natural number it cannot be smaller than everything in $E$ (else it would contain itself). But thus $m$ is either in $E$ or bigger than something in $E$. If $m$ is bigger than something in $E$ it must contain this, which thus needs to be smaller than itself. Basically the same argument why later we get $k=n^+$.

Comment: @ Lazy We don't have a notion of "smaller" number so far in the book. Every natural number is a set and if $n$ is a natural number and $m \in n$ we can write instead $m \lt n$. you should prove by set theoric tools rigorously.

Comment: In order to prove that $m$ is a natural number you should prove that $m \in \omega$ using the axioms and say exactly by which axiom. @Lazy

Comment: @OmidSadeghi Smaller means $<$, which is a symbol for $\in$, which by (3) is transitive, thus forms an order, so smaller does make sense. The axiom we use for proving $m$ is a natural number is P2, as $n^+$ is a natural number.

Comment: @ Lazy P.2 says if something is a natural number, the successor is natural number. it does not say the converse

Comment: @OmidSadeghi We do not neet the converse. The argument is: If $m\neq0,\mathbb N$ then $m$ contains an element $n$ so that $n^+$ (which is a natural number) is in $E$. Then we argue that $m=n$.

Comment: @ Lazy Could you please make your proof more organized and divide it into parts and name each part? For example we need a part that proves $m \in \omega$. I think at least you can devote a distinct part of your main proof to proving $m \in \omega$. You'd better format your proof such that every main part of the proof is standing out. Then I and everyone can understand it better. It is like a long sentence which at least it's hard for me to grasp.